QXmlStreamReader: How to detect whether a node contains child-nodes or only Text
I have an xml-document where a node with the same name is stored in two different ways:
Either
<element>A Text</element>

or
<element>
<name> A Text </name>
<value> 12 </value>
</element>

I'm parsing that document with QXMLStreamReader and I'm searching for a way how to detect whether it is only a Text or child nodes.
I tried allready
QXmlStreamReader& xml;
QString name;
xml.readNext();
QStringView text = xml.text();
if (text.isNull())
{
//Go into child nodes
    while (xml.readNextStartElement())
    {
        if (xml.name() == "name") 
            name = xml.readElementText()
        else
            xml.skipCurrentElement();
    }
}
else
{ 
    name = text.toString();
}

But that does not detect the childs in case of text.isNull()
It is currently not possible to change the parser, because this is a quite old and big one, and it also not possible to change the structure of the XML-File

Typo: you're creating test but then you check against text.

Any reason for not using the return value of QXmlStreamReader::readNext()? On another note, having an element that can be either text or a collection of other elements is bad XML design. For instance, XML schemas defined with XSD 1.0 cannot define something like that; the fact that you are struggling now is another clue you should revamp the schema. I've been there too and I can tell being stubborn is not going to help you.

@Atmo I agree with you regarding the XML-Design, but it is as it is. It was not designed by me

@Atmo, wouldn't mixed content https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#mixedContent allow both ways, even with XSD 1.0?
